# vi Error | Out of memory saving lines for undo - try using ed

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, vi, aix

While executing the following command on a large file:

```
vi largeFile.log
```

I get the following error:

```
Out of memory saving lines for undo - try using ed
```

My environment is:

- [AIX6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX)

I cannot add any Unix tools to this environment, I have tried the following commands:

- [less](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29) (Not installed)
- [ed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_%28text_editor%29) (I have no idea how to use this)

I am used to `vi` but cannot use it because this file is to big. I can use `ed` but I was wondering if there is an alternative. **All I need to do is read the last ten lines of this large file.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my  current solution:

```
tail -10 largeFile.log
```

This will read the last 10 lines from the end of the *largeFile.log* and display them in the console.

[Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.baseadmn/doc/baseadmndita/cmd_display_lastlines.htm)

Comment: Would you expand on what this does and how it works?

Comment: @Raystafarian Updated:-)